# How can I extract the same excel sheet from multiple files?

Tags: python, excel

I have a directory of similar excel files and want to extract the first sheet from each file and save it as a .csv file. Currently have code which works to extract and save sheet from individual file:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

f = glob.glob('filename.xlsx') # assume the path
for excel in f:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel) # if only the first sheet is needed.
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Comment: You can use wildcards in your [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#glob.glob) call to list all of the excel files in that directory: `f = glob.glob('*.xlsx')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all your files into a list using glob with a list comprehension:

```
files_to_be_read = glob.glob("*.xlsx") #Assuming you also have the path to the folder where the excel files are saved
for i in files_to_be_read:
    df_in = pd.read_excel(i) #You pass the path, pd.read_excel always uses the first sheet by default
    df_out = pd.to_csv(i+'.csv') #You will save the file with the same name, but in csv format
```

Comment: List comprehension isn't necessary, glob already returns a list.